# Why does my div has a vertical scroll even though overflow-y is set to visible?

Tags: html, css

I have an html table that I want to able scroll horizontally, and never vertically.

HTML goes basically like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="the-table"></table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

When the css is set this way. I see two scrolls: vertical and horizontal.

The table has several select elements in every row. I want them to overflow vertically when they are clicked.

The reason for the horizontal scroll is that I want it to be scrollable in the smaller screens.

Edit: overflow-y: hidden does not work because the select elements in every row. I absolutely want them to overflow vertically.

Comment: Set -y to auto.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

Comment: @Adriani6 It still creates a vertical scroll

Comment: @Duannx It isn't, this is about overflow-x: scroll and overflow-y: visible

Comment: Give the wrapper width and height to restrict, so that scroll is managed.

Comment: see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/3840840 - if you remove the `overflow-x:scroll;` it is working.